# Missing characters to convert the output of `tree` command using pandoc

Tags: xetex, pdftex, unicode, pandoc, markdown

I have a markdown document that contains the output of Unix `tree` command:

```
output/
├── cutadapt
│   ├── 0001.PbANKA_820_S1_R1.log
│   ├── 0002.PbANKA_820_S2_R1.log
│   └── 0003.PbANKA_R1.log
├── fastqc
│   ├── PbANKA_820_S1_R1_fastqc.html
│   ├── PbANKA_820_S1_R1_fastqc.zip
etc etc...
```

When I convert to pdf using pandoc I get a number of warnings:

```
pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex README.md -o README.pdf

[WARNING] Missing character: There is no ├ (U+251C) in font [lmmono10-regular]:!
[WARNING] Missing character: There is no ─ (U+2500) in font [lmmono10-regular]:!
[WARNING] Missing character: There is no ─ (U+2500) in font [lmmono10-regular]:!
[WARNING] Missing character: There is no │ (U+2502) in font [lmmono10-regular]:!
[WARNING] Missing character: There is no ├ (U+251C) in font [lmmono10-regular]:!
[WARNING] Missing character: There is no ─ (U+2500) in font [lmmono10-regular]:!
...etc etc
```

(Everything else in the document converts fine using a simple `pandoc README.md -o README.pdf`).

I understand I need to set the appropriate option `-V "mainfont:..."`? But I seem unable to get it right. I tried using:

```
fc-list ':charset=251C'
```

As I understand it, `fc-list` gives me a list of sets supporting character `├ (U+251C)`, but which of the many should I choose? Anyway, I tried a couple of them and the warnings persist:

```
pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex -V "mainfont:DejaVu Sans" README.md -o README.pdf

[WARNING] Missing character: There is no ├ (U+251C) in font [lmmono10-regular]:!
[WARNING] Missing character: There is no ─ (U+2500) in font [lmmono10-regular]:!
[WARNING] Missing character: There is no ─ (U+2500) in font [lmmono10-regular]:!
...
```

In addition, would it be possible to convert using `pdflatex` instead of `xelatex`?

---

Additional info:

```
pandoc -v
pandoc 2.17.1.1
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.22.1, texmath 0.12.4, skylighting 0.12.2,
citeproc 0.6.0.1, ipynb 0.2
User data directory: /home/dario/.local/share/pandoc
Copyright (C) 2006-2022 John MacFarlane. Web:  https://pandoc.org
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is no
warranty, not even for merchantability or fitness for a particular purpose.

xelatex -v
XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.3
Copyright 2017 SIL International, Jonathan Kew and Khaled Hosny.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the XeTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the XeTeX source.
Primary author of XeTeX: Jonathan Kew.
Compiled with ICU version 60.2; using 60.2
Compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.8.1; using 2.8.1
Compiled with Graphite2 version 1.3.11; using 1.3.11
Compiled with HarfBuzz version 1.7.2; using 1.7.2
Compiled with libpng version 1.6.34; using 1.6.34
Compiled with poppler version 0.62.0
Compiled with fontconfig version 2.12.6; using 2.12.6
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are probably putting the tree inside a code block, you have to specify the mono font as well:

`pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex -V "mainfont:DejaVu Sans" -V "monofont:DejaVu Sans Mono" README.md -o README.pdf`

[image]

Comment: `mainfont` -> `monofont` that was the trick! If it's not asking too much, any chance it could work using pdflatex?

Comment: I'd rather use `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex`